# C - Struct maker function causes different errors

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a function that fills a pointer to a struct. As I fill it with a GTK callback, I use a global pointer so the current "nivel" I'm using is accesible from other functions. I'm afraid I may have some memory problems.

The point is, I believe the memory is being "filled" alright. But, as soon as the program gets out of the function that calls the function to make the struct, I get one of several outcomes:

1 - Error: ***glibc detected*** corrupted double linked list

2 - Error: ***glibc detected***

3 - Segmentation fault.

4 - No error at all.

The error changes from execution to execution, so something tells me that it's gotta be about memory, perhaps I'm not handling the scope of the struct correctly, but I can't find the solution for it. I'm pretty sure the struct is being made correctly, though. Any help would be appreciated. The code is bellow, it has some parts ins spanish but I've commented the important bits. Thanks for the help!

```
//Struct, consists of a 2d array and size info.
struct nivel { 
    size_t filas;
    size_t columnas;
    int **mapa;
};

//Global current level pointer, I fill it with a call to the function within another function.

struct nivel *nivel_actual;

//Function to fill a struct, receives a pointer and the text file path.

    void    nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(struct nivel * nuevo_nivel, char *nombre_archivo ){
    g_print("Leyendo archivo...\n");
    nuevo_nivel->filas = 0;
    nuevo_nivel->columnas = 0;
    int *caracter;
    int leyo_columnas = 0;
    g_print("Leyendo archivo...\n");
    g_print("Obteniendo columnas...\n");
    FILE *archivo = fopen(nombre_archivo, "r");
    while ( (caracter = fgetc(archivo)) != EOF )  {
         if ( (!(leyo_columnas)) )
            nuevo_nivel->columnas++;
         if ((caracter == '\n') & (!(leyo_columnas)))
            leyo_columnas = 1;
         else if ((caracter == '\n'))
            nuevo_nivel->filas++;
    }
    nuevo_nivel->filas++;
    nuevo_nivel->columnas--;
    g_print("Columnas %d , Filas %d\n", nuevo_nivel->columnas, nuevo_nivel->filas);
    fclose(archivo);

    int x;

    nuevo_nivel->mapa = malloc( sizeof( int ) * nuevo_nivel->filas );

    for( x = 0; x < nuevo_nivel->filas; x++ )
        nuevo_nivel->mapa[x] = malloc( sizeof( int ) * nuevo_nivel->columnas );

    //parsear caracteres dentro del archivo
    int i=0,j=0;
    archivo = fopen(nombre_archivo, "r");
    while((caracter = fgetc(archivo)) != EOF) { //encontrar numero de filas
        g_print("%c",caracter);
        switch ((int)caracter){
            case '\n': i++; j=0; break;
            case ' ':nuevo_nivel->mapa[i][j]=0; j++;break;
            case '*':nuevo_nivel->mapa[i][j]=1; j++;break;
            case '+':nuevo_nivel->mapa[i][j]=2; j++;break;
            case 'A':nuevo_nivel->mapa[i][j]=3; j++;break;
            case 'R':nuevo_nivel->mapa[i][j]=4; j++;break;
            case 'S':nuevo_nivel->mapa[i][j]=5; j++;break;
    }
    }

    fclose(archivo);
}

//Within this function is the call to the struct maker function.

static void abrir_archivo( GtkWidget *ventana1, gpointer datos){ 
 GtkWidget *ventana_sel;
 GtkWidget *ventana = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 ventana_sel = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Seleccionar Archivo de Nivel",
                      GTK_WINDOW(ventana),
                      GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,
                      GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,
                      GTK_STOCK_OPEN, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                      NULL);
 if (gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (ventana_sel)) == GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT)
   {
     char *nombre_archivo;

     nombre_archivo = gtk_file_chooser_get_filename (GTK_FILE_CHOOSER (ventana_sel));
     g_print(nombre_archivo);

//Here is the call

     nivel_actual = malloc (sizeof (struct nivel));
     nuevo_nivel_desde_archivo(nivel_actual,nombre_archivo);
     g_print("Archivo parseado...\n");
   }
 gtk_widget_destroy (ventana_sel);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nuevo_nivel->mapa` is an array of arrays so it needs to allocate a number of `int` *pointers*

```
nuevo_nivel->mapa = malloc(sizeof(int*) * nuevo_nivel->filas);
```

If `sizeof(int) < sizeof(int*)` on your platform, you'll be writing beyond the end of the memory you've allocated.

Comment: Awesome :-) ... can't believe a simple * costed me most of the morning. Thanks a lot!!!